# ASK CLI INIT not working

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am new to `ask cli` but I have created skills directly on alexa online console and using lamda.

I installed `ask cli` using `npm install` from my Node.js command prompt. I then tried to initialize it using `ask init`.

`ask cli` asks me to select a default profile and then opens up Amazon login page. I then sign in but after that it opens up `127.0....` page on my IE which gives "cannot reach this page" error. Also in the cmd prompt it shows as listening to `localhost:9090` but it stucks there and nothing happens.

So I closed the Node.js command propmt and opened a fresh one. Here I tried the `ask clone` command but it gives me error "The property "token" does not exist.".

Please help me as I really need to get this done today itself

Comment: For me this works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47686780/2251733

Answer (score 3):

`ask init` ships with the [`--no-browser`](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#init-command) option which you can use as yet another approach.

- Run `ask init --no-browser`.
- Copy the generated link from the terminal an open it in your browser.
- It will ask you to login to your Amazon Developer console (don't mix it with AWS Console it's important).
- Once you logged in, copy the generated Auth Code and paste it back to terminal.

That should be suffice to configure `ask init`.

---

In additional you may want to configure AWS credentials. More info about [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#init-command).

Comment: I have did this, but the command prompt appears frozen and doesn't let me paste the code back in again. I am on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Turns out it was Nodejs was version 10. I uninstalled it and installed version 8.12 and then everything worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest downgrading to v8.12 as suggested by Amazon developer himself here: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/answers/190399/view.html

This helped in capturing correct token and the CLI is now responding perfectly. LTS v10 and current v11 are definitely not working with the current version of ask-CLI v1.4.9