# Is it possible to setup the ASK CLI profile without setting up an AWS profile

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ask-cli

I've been trying to install and setup the ASK CLI for a days now. I've followed the setup instructions and was able to install it. Whenever I try to run the ask init command and choose the "No. Skip AWS credentials association step.", a browser opens up and asks me to login to my developer account. I enter my credentials and just get redirected to a page that says unable to connect (Here's the link: http://127.0.0.1:9090/cb?code=ANjcJMpKRGqoqrSbiHdX&scope=alexa%3A%3Aask%3Askills%3Areadwrite+alexa%3A%3Aask%3Amodels%3Areadwrite+alexa%3A%3Aask%3Askills%3Atest+alexa%3A%3Aask%3Acatalogs%3Aread+alexa%3A%3Aask%3Acatalogs%3Areadwrite&state=Ask-SkillModel-ReadWrite).

I also tried using the ask init --no-browser command. I paste the generated url to a browser (I've tried Google Chrome, IE, Edge and Firefox and so far Firefox and IE works well). It gives me an authentication code but when I go back to the terminal, it's just frozen. I can't paste anything to it. I always get stuck at this point.

The reason I'm choosing "No. Skip AWS credentials association step." is because my skill endpoint is hosted as a web service in Azure and not using AWS Lambda. Am I missing anything? There were no errors in the installation process. I installed nodejs and git correctly. When I do ask --version in the terminal, the result is 1.4.7.

Does the ASK CLI not allow the skipping of the AWS profile setup?

A few details to make it clearer:

OS: Windows 10

Node JS: v10.13.0

NPM: 6.4.1

Git: git version 2.19.1.windows.1

ASK: 1.4.7

(I also found someone who experienced the same problem: [ASK CLI INIT not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48690820/ask-cli-init-not-working))